# Uploading files from Remote machine to AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, firewall, winrm

I have a requirement where I want to upload a directory/files from remote windows machine to AWS S3 bucket. The code is to be executed from the local machine and not the remote machine. Is there any solution approach I can use to get through this?

Edit: What firewall permissions/exceptions will I require to connect to the remote machine? I am using the winrm4j to connect to the remote machine. I am able to achieve this from my company network but the same fails in clients network.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution would be to open a login session to the remote Windows machine and run the upload command using the session.   For example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34933/can-i-connect-to-windows-machine-from-linux-shell/427739

Comment: How do you access the files in your remote machine?

Comment: @Kannaiyan I am trying to access them using winrm, but it fails in clients network.

Comment: @StephenC I am trying to do the same but the clients network obstructs me from connecting to the machine outside the network. I have edited my question.

Comment: The default winrm ports are in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management